# Can you cast/convert a Glass Mapper field to the corresponding Sitecore field?

Tags: c#, sitecore, glass-mapper

We use Sitecore and TDS, and I'm just getting into trying to do some refactoring taking advantage of Glass, and am trying to figure out if there's a way to take a Glass field (e.g. a Glass.Mapper.Sc.Field.Link) and cast/convert it to the underlying Sitecore LinkField (General Link) so I can use existing utility methods we have in place elsewhere that take a LinkField as a param (for example).

I've done some looking, but am not finding anything -- just trying to figure out if I need to create refactored versions of our utility methods to accept Glass objects, or if this is doable some other way. Thanks in advance if you can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment their isn't a utility for this. Glass disconnects the data source (i.e. the item) from the final object. This is done to give greater flexibility. Instead you should right a custom data handler that will return a general link field, see information here:
http://glass.lu/docs/tutorial/sitecore/tutorial19/tutorial19.html

It shouldn't take more than 20 lines of code to implement.